# Blender 2.80 where is the "interactive code panel" gone?

Tags: python, scripting

For a lack of a better term, please look at the following image.
I have been trying to drag around 2.80 like a maniac, was it moved somewhere else?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just that the "Info" editor isn't opened here by default. To get it back, simply open it somewhere else:

[image]

Comment: No worries, it happens to everyone. x)